# Failed to open temporary output file: Permission denied

Tags: azerothcore

ubuntu 20.04 install azeronthcore with docker,run ./acore.sh docker build , i had tried
several times but still not working.anyone could help me with this?thx!

```
     root@ubuntu:~/azerothcore-wotlk#  
     dos2unix: Failed to open temporary output file: Permission denied
     dos2unix: problems converting file env/dist/etc/authserver.conf.dockerdist to file 
     env/dist/etc/authserver.conf.dockerdist
     dos2unix: Failed to open temporary output file: Permission denied
     dos2unix: problems converting file env/dist/etc/worldserver.conf.dockerdist to file 
     env/dist/etc/worldserver.conf.dockerdist
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have permission to create a file in directory env/dist/etc/. dos2unix writes the result first to a temporary file. When something goes wrong in the middle, you still have the original file.